# Pasar parámetros vía AJAX a PHP de dos tipos, Array y campos únicos

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, array

Estoy intentando pasar parametros via AJAX a un PHP, una parte de los parámetros es un array (checkbox) y la otra campos unicos. Esta sintaxis me pasa correctamente el array que recojo en PHP con un foreach, pero no me pasa los parámetros dentro del success. Alguien sabe qué me dejo?

```
    //obtengo el array
    var selected = "";   
    $('#contact input[name="id_locale[]"]').each(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            selected += $(this).val();
        }
    });             

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selected);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {data : jsonString}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(response){
                $("#accion").val(data.accion);
                $("#usuario_cliente").val(data.usuario_cliente);
                $("#password_cliente").val(data.password_cliente);
                $("#nombre_cliente").val(data.nombre_cliente);

                alert('guardado');              
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera.

```
//array tipos de pago
var selectedtipospago = "";   
$('#contact input[name="id_tipospago[]"]').each(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        selectedtipospago += $(this).val();
    }
});       

var tipospago = JSON.stringify(selectedtipospago);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { 
        'accion': $("#accion").val(),
        'dominio': $("#dominio").val(),
        'protocolo_preferente': $("#protocolo_preferente").val(),
        'id_estructura': $("#id_estructura").val(),
        'jsonTipospago': tipospago
    },
    url: "index.php",
    success : function(data) {
        alert('guardado');
    }
});
```

Luego en PHP lo recojo así

```
$jsonIdiomas = json_decode(stripslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'jsonIdiomas')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Es por que la variable `data` no contiene nada. Si deseas mostrar el contenido de tu `response` desde el servidor deberias enviar los datos que requiere, pero por lo visto solo quieres mostrar lo que enviaste por AJAX, entonces tendrias que realizar esto

```
//obtengo el array
    var selected = "";   
    $('#contact input[name="id_locale[]"]').each(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            selected += $(this).val();
        }
    });             

        var data = JSON.stringify(selected);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {data : data}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(response){
                $("#accion").val(data.accion);
                $("#usuario_cliente").val(data.usuario_cliente);
                $("#password_cliente").val(data.password_cliente);
                $("#nombre_cliente").val(data.nombre_cliente);

                alert('guardado');              
            }
        });
```

Solo asignarle el valor de tu formulario a la variable `data`

```
var data = JSON.stringify(selected);
```

Espero te pueda servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo necesito enviar tanto el array como el resto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que no estas declarando "selected" como array:

```
 var selected = "";
```

debería ser:

```
 var selected = [];
```

Por otro lado, para comprobar si está checkeado el checkbox, tienes:

```
if (this.checked) {
     selected += $(this).val();
}
```

Y debería ser:

```
 if (this.prop("checked") == true) {  //Comprobar la propiedad checked del checkbox
     selected.push($(this).val());    //Añadir su valor al array
 }
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.